# Cascading Popovers: User Friendliness vs Guidelines

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

Before I begin, I would like to state that I KNOW the Apple Guidelines state that two popovers "should not" be on screen at one time, and that my app will likely get rejected if it do this, but I wanted opinions as to how this might work. Here is my dilemma:

The iPad doesn't have a numerical-only keyboard (it simply displays the normal keyboard). So I made a numerical keypad control in a popover (for elsewhere in the app) for ease of number entry.

I have a several fields in a popover that only allow numbers in them (by way of refusing any non-numerical keyboard input). Unfortunately, this means that now 90% of the keyboard is unresponsive when entering into these fields - and the numbers aren't even in the front "page" of the keyboard!

However, if I make the fields in the popover popup the numerical keyboard, this user interface confusion is eliminated! **But it goes against Apple Guidelines for Popovers!** (aside: they call them guidelines, yet they enforce them like hard-and-fast rules, right? :/ )

[image: Guideline-Eshewing Friendliness]

I'm asking opinions on what I should do here: should I go with one option or the other, or is there a third method I could use?

Comment: Can't you change those fields to sliders or pickers?

Comment: Question should probably be posted over at UI.StackExchange.

Comment: I was not aware of this UI.StackExchange offshoot site. Perhaps I'll pose my next question about this there... Also, the fields cannot be sliders: they can have any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to create a custom input layout that appears in place of the normal keyboard is described here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1063/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-custom-input-view-tutorial

Also, you *can* get the iPad to show the numbers on the "front page" of the keyboard by settings the text field's keyboardType to `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`.

Comment: I thank you for this link. I was not aware you could replace the keyboard like this. This may be what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with this number keyboard method for inputting numbers into text fields. Thank you for the fast response!

Comment: Another solution that you will see occasionally is to just put the number pad on a regular view that goes inside the same popover as the text fields themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just place your numberpad in a seperate view and either animate it in and out or make it moveable/dragable?

Comment: Wouldn't that be considered a popover-like control, which would be still against guidelines? Also, that seems like a bit more work than I'm willing to do for this little bit here; there's still a lot more app to be coded.

Comment: You can anchor a new view based of touch location exaclty like your picture and use an alpha to display/hide the view.  To the user it will look identical and it will comply with the guidlines.

Comment: I'm still not sure how that differs, because the guidelines also specify that "custom view designed to look and behave like a popover" also qualify in that "one popover at a time" rule. :/

Comment: Another idea is to place the numberpad in the same popover view (initially hidden) and then resize the popover horizonatally to show the numberpad upon uitextfield becoming active.